# Python- How to Combine 2 pandas.core.frame =.dataframe with the same column name together in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, append

So i got 2 pandas.core.frame.DataFrame like this:

anomalies:

```
             Sales  outlet
Date                     
2006-07-01    700       2
```

and this (anomalies2):

```
            Sales  outlet
Date                     
2011-03-01    206       1
2012-03-01    900       1
```

i tried combining them using :

```
anomalies3 = []
anomalies3.append(anomalies)
anomalies3.append(anomalies2)
print(anomalies3)
```

but the result are like this:

```
[            Sales  outlet
Date                     
2006-07-01    700       2,             Sales  outlet
Date                     
2011-03-01    206       1
2012-03-01    900       1]
```

how do i make it so the result were like

```
[            Sales  outlet
Date                     
2006-07-01    700       2                    
2011-03-01    206       1
2012-03-01    900       1]
```

Thanks in advance! and remember both are pandas.core.frame.DataFrame (type(anomalies) and type(anomalies2) give back pandas.core.frame.DataFrame)

Comment: I have some difficulties to "see" the list structure in both anomalies(2). Are they the outout of pandas.DataFrame?

Comment: sorry @cards, after i restart the kernel and try running all again, now it shows as pandas.core.frame.DataFrame and not list again

Comment: You can use `concat` https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.concat.html

Answer (score 0):

just use

anomalies3 = pd.concat([anomalies, anomalies2])